# Will the DLC for each platform be released at the same time?

Tags: dragon-age-2

For past BioWare games like Fallout, the Xbox 360 has enjoyed getting DLC some time before PlayStation 3. Is that true for Dragon Age II, or are all three platforms getting the DLC at the same time?

Comment: Dragon Age has multiplayer? News to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speculating about future DLC releases is outside of my capabilities, but the only existing paid DLC available now, [Exiled Prince](http://dragonage.bioware.com/da2/addon/exiled_prince/) is available now (and was available at launch) for all 3 systems (360, PS3 and PC) for the equivalent price of $7. Or if you got a copy of the Signature Edition of the game, it came with it.

Comment: what about addons for DAO? Was there any delay for PS3?

Comment: @IAdapter it appears they for the most part all released at the same time, no exclusives, see http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Downloadable_content_(Origins) if you want details. This doesn't mean a whole lot towards DA2, but you can take a guess I suppose.

Comment: Return to Ostagar Re-released (360 & PC): 29th January 2010
Release (PS3): 11th March 2010

Answer (score 1):

All platforms have had planned simultaneous DLC releases in North America and for the most part, this has held:

- *The Exiled Prince* and the *Black Emporium* were launch DLC, and were released for each platform on March 8th, 2011
- *Item Pack #1* was released on April 26th, 2011 for PC/Mac and Xbox 360, but due to the PSN breach, there was no way to distribute it to PS3 players until June 3rd, 2011
- *Legacy* launched on all three platforms on July 26th, 2011.
- *Mark of the Assassin* was released on all three platforms on October 11th, 2011.